# PHP - How to change the class of a link

Tags: php, html, css, web

I am trying to learn PHP for a website that I am building.  In CSS, I have a class, `nav a.thispage`, setup to make a 'button' on the navigation be the same color as the highlight.  It works beautifully.  But, as I added pages, I find that I needed to constantly update all of the HTML files of the site, over, and over again.  I found out that PHP could help me to automate this.  I use the following PHP, in my HTML to do this:

```
 <?php include 'content/header.php';?>
```

The header.php file has the following content:

```
<header>
  <h1><img id="headerimage" src="Images/GrandLodge.png"/>Lodge</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="social.php">Social</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="gamestores.php">Area Game Stores</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://someaddress" target="_blank">PFS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Now, because I am using this method, I can't just set the `class="thispage"` on the a tag.  Is there a way to set the class, dynamically, with PHP?  If so, how to I tell if the page loading the html is actually the page that needs it?  Is using PHP even the correct way to handle this, or should I be using JavaScript?

I know this is a lot, and I didn't really provide a lot of what I have done, but I can't actually seem to see what I need to do for this.  All I really need is a point in the right direction, rather than a full code sample.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: What does `header.php` have to do with `content.php`?

Comment: Dynamic HTML code is the purpose oho PHP...

Comment: Sorry, that should have said header.php, I corrected it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit oF PHP and JavaScript to handle this

```
<header>
   <h1><img id="headerimage" src="Images/GrandLodge.png"/>Lodge</h1>
   <nav>
     <ul>
       <li><a id="aHome" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
       <li><a id="aEvents" href="events.php">Events</a></li>
       <li><a id="aSocial" href="social.php">Social</a></li>
       <li><a id="aAbout" href="about.php">About</a></li>
       <li><a id="aContact" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a id="aGame" href="gamestores.php">Area Game Stores</a></li>
       <li><a id="aPFS" href="http://someaddress" target="_blank">PFS</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
```

Now suppose the visitor has landed on the About page. The code to check that and set the class name on the a tag would be

```
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/about.php') { 
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("aAbout").className = 'thispage';
 </script>
 <?php
   }
 ?>
```

Try it and let me know.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!  Now, the only question I have about this is, if JavaScript isn't enabled on the client, it should still grab the header (since PHP is server side) but it just won't add the class to the element, right?  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

```
    <header>
      <h1><img id="headerimage" src="Images/GrandLodge.png"/>Lodge</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
        <?php $basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
$class = $basename === 'index.php' || empty($basename) ? ' class="thispage"' : '';
          <li <?php if($basename=="index.php" || $basename==""){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li <?php if($basename=="events.php"){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
          <li <?php if($basename=="social.php"){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="social.php">Social</a></li>
          <li <?php if($basename=="about.php"){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
          <li <?php if($basename=="contact.php"){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          <li <?php if($basename=="gamestores.php"){?> class="thispage" <?php } ?>><a href="gamestores.php">Area Game Stores</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://someaddress" target="_blank">PFS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

**Updated another Simple way**

```
<header>
      <h1><img id="headerimage" src="Images/GrandLodge.png"/>Lodge</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
        <?php $basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
         $class = $basename === 'index.php' || empty($basename) ? ' class="thispage"' : '';
          <li <?= $class ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li <?= $class ?>><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
          <li <?= $class ?>><a href="social.php">Social</a></li>
          <li <?= $class ?>><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
          <li <?= $class ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          <li <<?= $class ?>><a href="gamestores.php">Area Game Stores</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://someaddress" target="_blank">PFS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header
```

Comment: Yeah or simply `$class = $basename === 'index.php'  || empty($basename) ? ' class="thispage"' : '';` And `<?= $class ?>` in every li.

Comment: its better to use ternary conditions, instead of long if conditions

Comment: You should think more about the people who will read you than yourself. First because the time you will save is time they will lose, and second because you might have to look at someone else's code someday, and if it's someone like you, you will hate it.

Comment: @Virus721 i am updated my answer for your instruction. Thanks friend

Comment: So, I have a question on this, as I like that it's PHP and I don't have to worry about the client machine.  Would I place this in `content/header.php` file?  Sorry for such a simple question, but I am just starting out with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In order for PHP to help you, you'd have to generate your navigation within a loop. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php 
    $menu = array(
        'Home'   => 'index.php',
        'Events' => 'events.php',
        'Social' => 'social.php',
        'About'  => 'about.php'
    );
?>

<?php foreach ($menu as $name => $href) : ?>
    <?php $class_name = basename(__FILE__) === $href ? 'thispage' : ''; ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" class="<?php echo $class_name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary code obfuscation if his links are static.

Comment: The OP inquired about a solution using PHP, and I think this is much cleaner (and more programmatic) than the other solution. It is also a viable solution which may interest the OP, or someone else down the line.